# rename all files and folder ftp in php language

Tags: php, ftp, rename, file-rename

i want rename all files and folder recursively i written a function that works and rename files but my problem when occurred when i make array of files and folders in a path, its not sort as parent child
so when i rename parent folder first , in next loop when function wants rename child said "No such file or directory" its true Error cause parent folder renamed a couple minutes ago

i changed my code but not help me
code for reading files and folder from ftp :

```
 if (!self::ftp_is_dir($resource, $thisPath)) {
        // for Files (anything that isnt a readable directory)
        if ($first == TRUE) {
            return array("Path doesn't Exist (" . $thisPath . ")");
        }
        $theList[] = $thisPath;
        return $theList;
    } else {
        $contents = ftp_nlist($resource, $thisPath);

        // For empty folders
        if (count($contents) == 0) {
            $theList[] = $thisPath;
            return $theList;
        } else {
            $theList[] = $thisPath;
        }

        // Recursive Part
        foreach ($contents As $file) {
            $theList = self::ftp_nlistr($resource, $file, $theList, FALSE);
        }

        return $theList;

    }
```

and this return array like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jYqT.png)

and this code i used for renaming folder and files

```
$replacers = array(" ", "", "  ", "-=", "=-", '©',"!", ";", "#", "@", "'", '<', '>');
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (preg_match('/' . implode('|', $replacers) . '/', $path) != 0) {

            $route = preg_replace('/ftp/', "ftp://ftp.mylocal.co", $path, 1);;
            if (is_dir($route)) {
                $newName = str_replace($replacers, "_", basename($path));
                $directory = pathinfo($path);
                if (ftp_rename($connectionID, $path, $directory['dirname'] . '/' . $newName)) {
                    Logger::setLog('renaming', "Renaming: $path to $newName");
                } else {
                    Logger::setLog('failed to renaming', "Renaming: $path to $newName");
                }
            } else {
                $newName = str_replace($replacers, "_", basename($path));
                $directory = pathinfo($path);

                if (ftp_rename($connectionID, $path, $directory['dirname'] . '/' . $newName)) {
                    Logger::setLog('renaming', "Renaming: $path to $newName");
                } else {
                    Logger::setLog('failed to renaming', "Renaming: $path to $newName");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk3kx.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jYqT.png)

```
public static function ftp_is_dir($conn, $dir)
{
    $cdir = ftp_pwd($conn);
    if (@ftp_chdir($conn, $dir)) {
        ftp_chdir($conn, $cdir);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the attempted code which does the renaming over ftp.

Comment: How are you renaming parent first, if you add child first? Why do you even rename the files? Show us the rename code!

Comment: hi dear friend this is my code for reading files and folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
+ folder
  - file1
  - file2
+ folder with space
  - file with space
```

... you currently first rename `/folder with space` to `/folder_with_space`.

And then you try to rename `/folder with space/file with space` to `/folder with space/file_with_space`. But that file does not exist anymore.

The easiest solution is to actually first rename children, then parent:

```
    $contents = ftp_nlist($resource, $thisPath);

    // Recursive Part
    foreach ($contents As $file) {
        $theList = self::ftp_nlistr($resource, $file, $theList, FALSE);
    }

    $theList[] = $thisPath;

    return $theList;
```